# MySQL implementation or JSON-Parsing - whats quicker?

Tags: android, mysql

I wonder which way is quicker.
To load JSON parsed data from an URL or use the SQL-Class of Java/Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

Load JSON parsed data from an URL more quicker than use the SQL-Class of Java/Objective-C.
You can visit these blogs for your reference.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/25/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-2/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

As far as only Json parsing is concerned, then Json parsing is quicker. But as you said Json parsed data from an URL, that means getting JSon data is dependent on network operation too, which is expensive task to do as well as it require you to add permission to access internet and you won't be able to get Json data if you won't be having internet connection.

```
So you should think firstly on availability of data and then on performance.
```

Comment: I was thinking about checking the availability first and then, if connected, load json from an url. the idea behind was to outsource as much as possible to php and my server.